# How to cache page after clicking using phonegap?

Tags: html, cordova

I begin to develop mobile app using PhoneGap. First I make 2 .html files named index.html and place.html

In index.html I use $.get() method to get json data from web service and then show on  HTML tag.

When user click link from index.html page it going to place.html. In place.html I put back button like

```
<a href="index.html">Back</a>
```

for back to index.html page.

A problem is when I click back button to index.html page it run $.get() method when page is loaded.

How to cache index.html page? When I clicking back button, it use same data from the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery mobile?

You don't have to actually incorporate the entire library, but only utilize the

```
<div class="home-page" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true" >
```

attributes on the Home page container. Another thing to note is that all your pages need the data-role="page" attribute for jQM to work.

By default, jQM has disabled caching, you can enable it in JavaScript as follows

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
```

Reference: [jQM Documentation on caching pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-cache.html)

Comment: I try to put data-rol="page" and data-dom-cache="true" into index.html and place.html. A problem is when I click a link on index.html to place.html page, place.html don't call $.get() method.

Comment: You will need to call $.get() on an event as follows:
    <br>$(document).bind('pagechange', yourFunction);
    Function yourFunction(){ $.get(); }

This is because when a page is changed you will have to rebind all elements and call your initializations in this pagechange bound function, since the new page is loaded via Ajax.
Hope that helps.

Comment: You can also use $.ajax and pass the option 'cache: false' so that your $.get request is not sent multiple times. EXAMPLE:
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        url: "http://domain.tld"
    });